# Espresso will not perform typeText ViewAction on SearchView

Tags: android

My code looks like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.search_view)).perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.search_view)).perform(typeText(search_query));
```

For some reason, even though I see the search bar and keyboard getting displayed briefly and the target view is a SearchView, I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
((is displayed on the screen to the user) and (supports input methods or is assignable from class: class android.widget.SearchView))
Target view: "SearchView{id=2131362837, res-name=search_view, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=126, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@940faa7, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the runtime error because you're trying to perform `typeText` on `SearchView` which is a non-editable field. [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView) is simply a `LinearLayout` that contains an editable field, so you should change your matcher to something like:

```
onView(allOf(supportsInputMethods(), isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.search_view))))
    .perform(typeText(search_query));
```